# Having trouble with rich text editing in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, rte

I am trying to add rich text editing to my application and I cant seem to get it to work. This is just one example but I cant get it to work. Can anyone please tell me what I am missing?

Here is the code that I have so far... this is in the `.h` file

```
private slots:
void newFile();
void open();
bool save();
bool saveAs();
void about();
void documentWasModified();
void bold();
```

and this is in the `.cpp` file... also I have `#include <QTextEdit>`

```
    void MainWindow::bold()
{
}
```

along with this down the page a little more

```
boldAct = new QAction(tr("&Bold"), this);
    boldAct->setCheckable(true);
    boldAct->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Bold);
    boldAct->setStatusTip(tr("Make the text bold"));
    connect(boldAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(bold()));
```

Comment: There is a textedit demo with Qt that does exactly this.  Why don't you have a look at how it's implemented?

Comment: I have tried looking at what you are talking about and I have added all the things I thought were it from the reference document and nothing works. The button can get pressed and everything but the text does not get bolded.

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more detail about the implementation of your bold() slot before anyone can help you.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm kind of new at this. What I presented is all that I have. All I have is a button to type bold and to make selected text bold. The only thing is is it won't bold. I need to know what I'm missing. I apologize for not knowing what you need

Comment: It's sad to say I have even resorted to copy pasting everything I thought I needed and changed the names to match mine but still does not work

Comment: So assuming you have created a QTextEdit, all you need to do is, in your bold() slot, call textEdit->setFontWeight(QFont::Bold), and that should work.

Comment: WOW! thank you so much I cant believe It was that easy. I appreciate your time and knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

QAction signal's signature is not correct. It should be

```
connect(boldAct, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(bold()));
```

or even

```
connect(boldAct, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), SLOT(bold()));
```

Also [QObject::connect()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect) returns a boolean value, describing connection success.

[QMetaObject::checkConnectArgs()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#checkConnectArgs) is useful to verify that signal and slot can be connected.